# Censoring words in textarea that are equal to array`s words

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I would like to get some help doing this task.
I need to censure words in text area that are simillar to the words in my array.All is working good exept the censuring part! It should cover every letter in a censure word like(car should be ***),but unfortunately it covers it like one single *.
Maybe indexOf can be usefull here? Waiting for answers<3

It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdHbu.png)

Here is my code i want you to improve:

```
<script>
    var words = ["meat", "lol"];
    document.querySelector('.container p').innerHTML = words.join(" ");
    document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = function () {
            words.push(document.getElementById('newWord').value);
            document.querySelector('.container p').innerHTML = words.join(" ");
        }
        //Replacing
    document.getElementById('btnCensura').onclick = function () {
            var str = document.getElementById('tArea').value;
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (str.match(words[i])) {
                    str = str.replace(words[i], "*");
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('tArea').value = str;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(words[i], "*".repeat(words[i].length));`

Comment: Also don't bother calling match. It actually makes this less efficient

Comment: @4castle thanks mate,it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

normal `.replace` only replace first occurrence, use regex if you want to replace all matched text in textarea

```
document.getElementById('btnCensura').onclick = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById('tArea').value;
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(words[i], "g");
    str = str.replace(re, "*".repeat(words[i].length));
  }
  document.getElementById('tArea').value = str;
}
```